# How do I create a Shared Drive with Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-workspace

How do I *create* a Shared Drive with Google Apps Script?

Comment: Take a look here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/create

Comment: That's probably the route to go. Just curious if I can do this with Apps Script, apart from the Drive API.

Comment: I don't think so.  Shared drives are  pretty new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is possible with the [Advanced](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) [Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-sdk) service

- Keep in mind that Apps Script uses the Drive API version v2
- The process to create a new shared drive with Drive API v2 is described [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/manage-shareddrives#create_shared_drives)
- Incorporating this into Apps Script, the corresponding method would be `Drive.Drives.insert(resource, requestId);`
- `requestId` is an Id you choose to assign to the drive
- `resource` is the body of the request, it should contain the drive name

Sample:

`Drive.Drives.insert({"name": "mySharedDrive"}, 12345);`